# How to use the DOM locators in Selenium

Tags: selenium

I've the HTML source like this,

```
<input type="image" onclick="return logSub();" src="/images/Login_submit.gif" width="105" height="33" border="0" />
```

Here there is no ID or NAME. So I can only locate this using image index (which is hard) or using the src tag? But I dont know how use the src tag?

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or with css:

`css=input[type=image], [src="/images/Login_submit.gif"]`

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I want to do like this,

selenium.click("dom=document.getElementsByTagName('input')('src=/images/Login_submitBut.gif')");

I think, only using image is the option in selenium. This works,

selenium.click("dom=document.getElementsByTagName('input')(1)");

Answer (score 2):

See my answer to a previous question here: [selenium: Is it possible to use the regexp in selenium locators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007367/selenium-is-it-possible-to-use-the-regexp-in-selenium-locators/2007531#2007531)

Basically the `dom=` protocol allows you to use javascript to locate elements for Selenium.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried

```
//input[@src='/images/Login_submit.gif']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this locator:

```
//input[contains(@src, 'Login_submit.gif')].
```