# Clicking links by regexp in python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I've been looking around and trying to find a way to click on a link in selenium that's matched by a regexp.

Here is the code that works;

```
from selenium import selenium
sel = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
sel.start()
sel.open('/pubmed')
sel.type("search_term", "20032207[uid]")
sel.click("search")
sel.click("linkout-icon-unknown-vir_full")
```

However if I search across different IDs the link-text will be different but it always matches the regexp `linkout-icon[\w-_]*`.

But I can't seem to find the right command for clicking a link which matches a regexp ... I've tried:

```
sel.click('link=regex:linkout-icon[\w-_]*')
sel.click('regex:linkout-icon[\w-_]*')
sel.click('link=regexp:linkout-icon[\w-_]*')
sel.click('regexp:linkout-icon[\w-_]*')
```

But none of them seem to work at all.  Any suggestions?

EDIT:

So after comments in an answer below:  The clicked item is actually an image with the id=linkout-icon-unknown-viro_full.  The full line is below:

```
<a href="http://vir.sgmjournals.org/cgi/pmidlookup?view=long&amp;pmid=20032207" ref="PrId=3051&amp;itool=Abstract-def&amp;uid=20032207&amp;nlmid=0077340&amp;db=pubmed&amp;log$=linkouticon" target="_blank"><img alt="Click here to read" id="linkout-icon-unknown-vir_full" border="0" src="http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/corehtml/query/egifs/http:--highwire.stanford.edu-icons-externalservices-pubmed-standard-vir_full.gif" /></a> </div>
```

If your wondering I got the code from the Selenium IDE recorder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sel.click` can take an XPath as an argument. Using [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) I found (what I believe is) the XPath to "linkout-icon-unknown-vir_full" link:

```
sel.click("//*[@id='linkout-icon-unknown-vir_full']")
```

Using the above command takes me to [this page](http://vir.sgmjournals.org/cgi/content/full/91/5/1335).

---

I wasn't able to get `matches` to work -- I'm not sure why -- but this seems to work using [contains](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_functions.asp#string):

```
sel = selenium.selenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox", "http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/")
sel.start()
sel.open('/pubmed')
sel.type("search_term", "20032207[uid]")
sel.click("search")
sel.wait_for_page_to_load(30000)
sel.click("//*[contains(@id,'linkout')]")
```

Comment: Right idea but I need a regexp since I'm going to be taking these from lists of searches.  For different searches I'll need to match different links.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are very close.  First, `regexp:` is the right text pattern for saying you want to use a regular expression.

The other thing that probably isn't quite right is saying `link=`, as that refers to the *text* of the link, i.e.:

```
<a href="path/to/mylink">Text of the link, this is what will be searched</a>
```

So what part of the anchor do you want to use your regular expression on, the href?

Something that might lead towards the right answer is this:  [selenium: Is it possible to use the regexp in selenium locators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007367/selenium-is-it-possible-to-use-the-regexp-in-selenium-locators/2007531#2007531)

Maybe that get function could be repurposed to search all `a.href` properties for your regexp and then return the XPath of each of them to then be fed to `click()`

Answer (score 0):

After doing some hacking around I've come up with probably the most asinine way to do it but it works until someone can provide me with a better answer:

```
import re
val = re.findall('linkout-icon-unknown[\w-]*', sel.get_html_source())[0]
sel.click(val)
```

It requires me to search the entire html and will likely come up with issues if the design changes.

I'd love to see a more robust method.