# Using XPath wildcards in attributes in Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, xpath

I want to use Wildcards in my attributes. For example, this is my regular XPath:

```
//input[@id='activation:j_idt84:voId:1']`
```

I want to replace the `j_idt` number with a wildcard because the number is dynamic. I'm looking for something like this:

```
//input[@id='activation:*:voId:1']
```

I don't know how to solve that issue. Is my idea even possible?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no string wildcards in XPath. However you can use multiple `contains()` and `starts-with()` to filter things like this.

```
//input[starts-with(@id, 'activation:') and contains(@id, ':voId:1')]
```

Also, this answer could be useful too: [selenium: Is it possible to use the regexp in selenium locators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2007367/selenium-is-it-possible-to-use-the-regexp-in-selenium-locators/2007531#2007531)

Answer (score 4):

You *can* use string wildcards using the `matches` function which is available in XPath 2.0:

```
//input[matches(@id, 'activation:.*:voId:1')]
```

Comment: This way doesn't work in my code. The solution of complex857 works. But thanks a lot!

Comment: Selenium [delegates xpath to the underlying browser](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=3009) so once browsers implement them it should start working.