# lxml startswith for xpath

Tags: python, lxml

How would I get the following (using the `%` for a LIKE statement) --

```
assets['HasEN'] = self.node.xpath('//data_file[@role="source"]/locale[@name="en%"]')
```

In other words, the name could be `en`, it could be `en-US`, it could be `en-GB`, etc.

Is there a way to do that with `lxml` or do I have to do that after parsing the XML?

Comment: Maybe this will help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495723/using-xpath-wildcards-in-attributes-in-selenium-webdriver

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this syntax:

```
/locale[starts-with(@name, "en")]
```