# Using xpath for locating an element in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

I am trying to automate a web application using `Selenium WebDriver` with `Java`

[image]

I want to click on `"Create Tournaments"`link. I used `xpath` for identifying that element. But I'm getting the error

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: 
Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='createtournaments_li']/a"}
```

Can anybody help me in this..?

Code:

```
package User;

import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import junit.framework.Assert;
import jxl.Sheet;
import jxl.Workbook;
import jxl.read.biff.BiffException;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class QZO_Create_Tournament {

        WebDriver driver;
        private Properties properties;
        private final String PROPERTY_FILE_NAME = "constant.properties";

        public QZO_Create_Tournament() {
            properties = new Properties();
            try {
                InputStream inputStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(PROPERTY_FILE_NAME);
                if(null != inputStream)
                {
                    properties.load(inputStream);
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @BeforeTest

        public void openBrowser()
        {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\MyProjects\\SeleniumTrials\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            driver= new ChromeDriver();
            driver.get(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADMIN_URL"));
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
        }

        @Test

        public void login() throws BiffException, IOException, InterruptedException{

            WebElement username=driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADMIN_USERNAME")));
            username.clear();
            username.sendKeys("admin");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD")));
            password.sendKeys("123456");
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            WebElement continuebutton=driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_ADMIN_CONTINUE")));
            continuebutton.click();
             Thread.sleep(20000);
        }


@Test

        public void createtournament(){

         driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
         WebElement createtournament=driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_CREATETOURNAMENT")));
         // WebElement createtournament = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/Admin/CreateEditTournaments']"));
         createtournament.click();
         Select tournamenttype = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath(properties.getProperty("VAR_TOURNAMENTTYPE")))); 
         tournamenttype.selectByVisibleText("Planned Tournament");}}
```

Properties file :

```
VAR_ADMIN_USERNAME = //*[@id='username_txt']
VAR_ADMIN_PASSWORD = //*[@id='password_txt']
VAR_ADMIN_CONTINUE = //*[@id='main-section']/div/div/section[2]/div[2]/a/span
VAR_CREATETOURNAMENT = //*[@id='createtournaments_li']/a
VAR_TOURNAMENTTYPE = //*[@id='main-section']/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/ul/li/div/div/select
```

Comment: Try having a look at this

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495723/using-xpath-wildcards-in-attributes-in-selenium-webdriver

Comment: How many nodes does that xpath return?

Comment: @Jsmith2800 : I didn't get that

Comment: @Will: how can i count the number of nodes..? Dont know that. i'm new to selenium

Comment: @Amrutha in the lower left corner of the firepath window there will be something that says, "X matching node(s)."  That's how you can be sure your xpath is finding one node only - the one you care about.  If it's more than one then your xpath need some refinement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='createtournaments_li']/a"));
```

Make sure the code is not part of an `<iframe>` and that the page is loaded before executing it.

Make sure you are on the right page. It looks like your test is not logging in before you search for the element. The login test is a separate test. The create tournament test will start from the url state in the @BeforeTest

Comment: Actually dot makes no difference in this case

Comment: @Nick : driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='createtournaments_li']/a"));   This didn't worked.  And the code is not part of an <iframe>

Comment: Make sure the page is loaded before the line is executed. Add a breakpoint or a Thread.sleep just to make sure.

Comment: @Nick : Thread.sleep is already added and the page is loaded before the line is executed

Comment: The xpath should be okay. It must be something else. Can you share the source/code?

Comment: You are on the wrong page. The login test runs independently. Login again in the second test before you try to create a tournament. Extract the login logic in a method.

Comment: If my answer helped you out, you can accept it so other people can see the question is solved.

Answer (score 0):

use implicit wait may be it will help you out, i had a same problem and implicit wait work like a charm.
http://www.software-testing-tutorials-automation.com/2014/01/how-to-use-implicit-wait-in-selenium.html

Comment: Tried implicit wait. but same issue