# selenium XPATH matches method

Tags: java, regex, xpath, selenium

I have problems running the matches XPATH method:

```
@Test(groups = "regression")
@Parameters( { "baseUri", "locale" })
public void testShopping(String baseUri, String locale) throws Exception{
    session().allowNativeXpath("false");
    String shoppingLink = session().getAttribute("//div[@id='footernav_links']//a[matches(@href,'.*shopping.*')]/@href");
    LOGGER.info(shoppingLink);
}
```

throws exception

`1:25.871 INFO - Command request: getAttribute[//div[@id='footernav_links']//a[matches(@href,'.*shopping.*')]/@href, ] on session 057af825ff224b16877a61b97b974b72
13:31:25.912 INFO - Got result: ERROR: Element //div[@id='footernav_links']//a[matches(@href,'.*shopping.*')]/ not found on session 057af825ff224b16877a61b97b974b72
13:3`

I am using FF3.6 and got the motivation for this code from the article

[how-to-use-regex-in-selenium-locators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398705/how-to-use-regex-in-selenium-locators)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `contains` as follows:

```
xpath=id('footernav_links')//a[contains(@href, '/shopping/')]@href
```

Also, the `/` before the final `@` shouldn't be necessary, and you can simplify `//div[@id='footernav_links']` to `id('footernav_links')` as shown above. Note that you will need the `xpath=` prefix if you do this though.

---

Alternatively, you could use a CSS locator:

```
css=#footernav_links a[href*=/shopping/]@href
```

Comment: Thanks ...... this syntax is more compact and I can re-use the expression thru string substituion too. Saved some lines of code :-)

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. I now use the following syntax

```
session().allowNativeXpath("false");
String shoppingLink = session().getAttribute(
    "//div[@id='footernav_links']//a[matches(@href,'/shopping/')]/@href");
LOGGER.info(shoppingLink);
```

the Link I am searching for is of the form
`http://mysite.com/wcs/shopping/overview?cc=gb&lc=en`
I am not sure if this is completely correct though.