# How to use regex in Selenium Webdriver xpath?

Tags: java, regex, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have the following `WebElement` which can locate using `xpath`:

`/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[335]/div[1]/span`

In the above locator, `div[335]` number randomly changes. I want to use regex and use the `xpath` as element locator.

Can anyone please let me know the regular expression to use with the above `xpath`?

I'm using Selenium Webdriver with Java. IDE is Intellij and I'm testing on Chrome browser.

I'm going to use the above mentioned `xpath` as below:

```
@FindBy(how = How.XPATH, using =/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div/div[335]/div[1]/span

public WebElement totalSuppliers;
```

Comment: I could not work out your task here. Why do you need to use regex? And anyway, might there be a better way to find any steps in your long xpath, such as ID or class name? An xpath like this is extremely brittle, a minor change in the webpage can break it and it will be very hard to debug.

Comment: what changes the 335? or why is it changed? you'll need to generate a dynamic selector more information would be helpful

Comment: Does this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398705/how-to-use-regex-in-selenium-locators

Comment: good link for using xpaths http://test-able.blogspot.ie/2016/04/xpath-selectors-cheat-sheet.html

Comment: This question would have been resolved in no time if you (OP, **user1767083**) would have added a brief **HTML snippet** of the element you are targeting and it's enclosing containers.

Comment: simply try :=/html/body/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[4]/div/div//div/div[1]/span

Comment: @iamdanchiv       below is the html snippet <div class="kui-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in suppliers.Items" kg-href="/app/index.html#/suppliercard/card/489">
<div class="kui-row ng-scope" ng-repeat="item in suppliers.Items" kg-href="/app/index.html#/suppliercard/card/490">
<div class="kui-row kui-row-foot">
<div class="ng-binding">
Total number of suppliers :
<span class="ng-binding">333</span>
</div>
<div class="ng-binding">Total </div>
<div class="ng-binding">60,407,905.98</div>
<div class="ng-binding">64,775.40</div>
</div>
</div>

Comment: @ Lee92 335 is changing and it represent the no of records found when search

Comment: @ kushal: your solution is not working.....

Comment: Can you give us the complete DOM in a good readable format?