# RegEx for matching phone numbers with Selenium in HTML tags

Tags: c#, selenium

NOT an element locator. I need to make sure a phone number (any number) is on the page. If I can find it in a specific element that would be awesome.

```
<div id="Only456">(555) 555-1212</div>
```

Comment: I think my question confused Emma, my apologies. I have the regex, but don't know the Selenium command to use it on text.

Comment: I think you want to validate the phone number is displayed in the right pattern. Is it right?

Comment: This is a Selenium question, not a regex question. I will remove the regex tags.

Comment: Do you want to check if the phone number is present in the page? Any reason, why  don't you want to use the element locator like xpath?

Comment: Not that I don't want to - I am confused as to how.

Answer (score 1):

It may not be the best idea to do so using regular expressions, however if you have /wish to, You can design/modify/change your expressions in [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/x0TLH7/1).

[image]

You might want to add any char that you might have in this char list: `[0-9-\s()+]`

```
<(.+)>([0-9-\s()+]+)<\/(.+)>
```

You can also add more boundaries to it, especially instead of using `(.+)`. You can replace them with a list of chars as well such as:

```
<(.+)>([0-9-\s()+]+)<\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)
```

#### RegEx Circuit

You can visualize your expressions in [jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24):

[image]

#### C# Test

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Example
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string pattern = @"<(.+)>([0-9-\s()+]+)<\/(.+)>";
        string substitution = @"$2";
        string input = @"<div id=""Only456"">(555) 555-1212</div>
<h1>+1 800 555-1212</h1>
<span class=""row"">555-555-1212</span>";
        RegexOptions options = RegexOptions.Multiline;

        Regex regex = new Regex(pattern, options);
        string result = regex.Replace(input, substitution);
    }
}
```

#### JavaScript Demo

```js
const regex = /<(.+)>([0-9-\s()+]+)<\/(.+)>/gm;
const str = `<div id="Only456">(555) 555-1212</div>
<h1>+1 800 555-1212</h1>
<span class="row">555-555-1212</span>`;
const subst = `$2`;

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Substitution result: ', result);
```

#### Selenium

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398705/how-to-use-regex-in-selenium-locators) might be helpful.